# The 'this' keyword behaves differently in React

Tags: reactjs

In [vanilla JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software), the keyword *this* in the static methods of a class refers to the class itself, but in React, in the static method getDerivedStateFromProps, I noticed that this word does not refer to the class, and when logging in the console, it is undefined. What is the reason for this different behavior?

I try use the React life cycle method.

Comment: Could you add some relevant code for us to take a look at? Where exactly are you using `this`?

Comment: It's not React, it's Javascript itself. The value of `this` depends how a function is called. If you call `const thisFunction = function () {
 return this;
}` in a browser you'll get `undefined` too.

Comment: Check [What is `this` in React?](https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480). It explains why `this` is different depending on context, how `call` and `apply` change that context and why arrow functions avoid it. Which is why they're used so much in React.

Answer (score 1):

In React, the `this` keyword is used to refer to the current instance of a component class. It allows you to access the component's props, state, and methods within its class definition.

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is a lifecyle method that is invoked before the component is initiated and therefore you won't have access to the `this` keyword inside it.

If you need to access the props inside, use the props argument like this:

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
      console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps method is called');
      return { email: props.email };
   }
```

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops